# An Idris proof about `mod`

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I was trying to write a proof in Idris regarding the following subtraction-based mod operator:

```
mod : (x, y : Nat) -> Not (y = Z) -> Nat
mod x Z p = void (p Refl)
mod x (S k) _ = if lt x (S k) then x else helper x (minus x (S k)) (S k)
  where total
        helper : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Nat
        helper Z x y = x
        helper (S k) x y = if lt x y then x else helper k (minus x y) y
```

The theorem I wanted to prove is that the remainder as produced by "mod" above is always smaller than the divider. Namely,

```
mod_prop : (x, y : Nat) -> (p : Not (y=0))-> LT (mod x y p) y
```

I constructed a proof but was stuck by a final hole. My full code is pasted below

```idris
    mod : (x, y : Nat) -> Not (y = Z) -> Nat
    mod x Z p = void (p Refl)
    mod x (S k) _ = if lt x (S k) then x else helper x (minus x (S k)) (S k)
      where total
            helper : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Nat
            helper Z x y = x
            helper (S k) x y = if lt x y then x else helper k (minus x y) y
    
    lteZK : LTE Z k
    lteZK {k = Z} = LTEZero
    lteZK {k = (S k)} = let ih = lteZK {k=k} in
                        lteSuccRight {n=Z} {m=k} ih 
    
    lte2LTE_True : True = lte a b -> LTE a b
    lte2LTE_True {a = Z} prf = lteZK
    lte2LTE_True {a = (S _)} {b = Z} Refl impossible
    lte2LTE_True {a = (S k)} {b = (S j)} prf = 
      let ih = lte2LTE_True {a=k} {b=j} prf in LTESucc ih

    
    lte2LTE_False : False = lte a b -> GT a b
    lte2LTE_False {a = Z} Refl impossible
    lte2LTE_False {a = (S k)} {b = Z} prf = LTESucc lteZK
    lte2LTE_False {a = (S k)} {b = (S j)} prf = 
      let ih = lte2LTE_False {a=k} {b=j} prf in (LTESucc ih)
    
    total
    mod_prop : (x, y : Nat) -> (p : Not (y=0))-> LT (mod x y p) y
    mod_prop x Z p = void (p Refl)
    mod_prop x (S k) p with (lte x k) proof lxk
      mod_prop x (S k) p | True  = LTESucc (lte2LTE_True lxk)
      mod_prop Z (S k) p | False = LTESucc lteZK 
      mod_prop (S x) (S k) p | False with (lte (minus x k) k)  proof lxk'
        mod_prop (S x) (S k) p | False | True = LTESucc (lte2LTE_True lxk')
        mod_prop (S x) (S Z) p | False | False  = LTESucc ?hole
```

Once I run the type checker, the hole is described as follows:

```
- + Main.hole [P]
 `--          x : Nat
              p : (1 = 0) -> Void
            lxk : False = lte (S x) 0
           lxk' : False = lte (minus x 0) 0
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Main.hole : LTE (Main.mod, helper (S x) 0 p x (minus (minus x 0) 1) 1) 0
```

I am not familiar with the syntax of `Main.mod, helper (S x) 0 p x (minus (minus x 0) 1) 1` given in the *idris-holes* window. I guess `(S x) 0 p` are the three parameters of "mod" while `(minus (minus x 0) 1) 1` are the three parameters of the local "helper" function of "mod"?

It seems that it's time to leverage an induction hypothesis. But how can I finish up the proof using induction?

Answer (score 2):

```
(Main.mod, helper (S x) 0 p x (minus (minus x 0) 1) 1)
```

can be read as

- `Main.mod, helper` - a qualified name for `helper` function, which is defined in the `where` clause of the `mod` function (`Main` is a module name);
- Arguments of `mod` which are also passed to `helper` - `(S x)`, `0` and `p` (see [docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#where-clauses)):

> Any names which are visible in the outer scope are also visible in the
>   where clause (unless they have been redefined, such as xs here). A
>   name which appears only in the type will be in scope in the where
>   clause if it is a parameter to one of the types, i.e. it is fixed
>   across the entire structure.

- Arguments of `helper` itself - `x`, `(minus (minus x 0) 1)` and `1`.

---

Also below is another implementation of `mod` which uses [`Fin n`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Fin.idr) type for the remainder in division by `n`. It turns out to be easier to reason about, since any value of `Fin n` is always less than `n`:

```
import Data.Fin

%default total


mod' : (x, y : Nat) -> {auto ok: GT y Z} -> Fin y
mod' Z (S _) = FZ
mod' (S x) (S y) with (strengthen $ mod' x (S y))
    | Left _ = FZ
    | Right rem = FS rem

mod : (x, y : Nat) -> {auto ok: GT y Z} -> Nat
mod x y = finToNat $ mod' x y

finLessThanBound : (f : Fin n) -> LT (finToNat f) n
finLessThanBound FZ = LTESucc LTEZero
finLessThanBound (FS f) = LTESucc (finLessThanBound f)

mod_prop : (x, y : Nat) -> {auto ok: GT y Z} -> LT (mod x y) y
mod_prop x y = finLessThanBound (mod' x y)
```

Here for convenience I used [auto implicits](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html#auto-implicit-arguments) for proofs that `y > 0`.